# difference between curl commandline and code

Tags: php, curl

What's the difference between:

```
curl -v --data "username=username&password=password&sessionDataKey=5c4a5bb8-eb14-44a0-a745-50f54024a1b2" https://api.toonapi.com/commonauth/
```

and:

```
$url = 'https://api.toonapi.com/commonauth/';
    $session_key = $this->curlSessionKey();
$data_string = 'username=' . $username . '&password=' . $password . '&sessionDataKey=' . $session_key;
  //json_encode($data);


$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);
```

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong

Comment: You should probably remove your credentials from your post

Comment: thx removed it from the next forgot in the above one

Comment: Without looking at the code: The user that is running the script. Which means (probably...) different filesystem permissions, etc.

Comment: same user is running the script